# Which adb commands does eclipse use to run app?

Tags: android, eclipse, adb, adt

I'm working on an app that uses device admin. If I run the app on a device using eclipse, then make a minor change to the code, then run the app again, the app runs as you'd expect with the new change.

However, if the second time I run the app I use adb install I get:

Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_ALREADY_EXISTS]

If I try to uninstall then reinstall, the uninstall fails because the app is device admin. This has led me to wonder which adb commands eclipse executes when you select run. I've looked for some sort of "update" command but I couldn't find one. Anyone know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use "adb install -r yourapp.apk" to install your system apk again.
If you want to run through command line, use
"adb shell am start -n acticityname_withpackage"